# Perl : Can anyone tell me how to resolve this warnings

Tags: perl, warnings

Code part 1:

```
      my $length = @array;

269   for (my $j=1; $j <= $length; $j+=1) {
270
271     if ( $fields[$j] =~ /dat/) {
    
         }}
```

Warning 1:

```
Use of uninitialized value within @array in pattern match (m//) at wrk.pl line 270
```

Code part 2: Here I am trying to convert the decimal to hexadecimal

```
70 while (my $line = <DATA>) {
71     $line =~ s/ '([0-9]*)' / sprintf '0x%x', $1/eg;
72     print OUT $line;
       }
```

Warning 2:

```
Argument "" isn't numeric in sprint at wrk.pl line 71
```

**Update**

Above both warnings has now resolve after I put `for (my $j=1; $j <= $#array; $j+=1)`  and for 2nd warning I change `$line =~ s/ '([0-9]+)' / sprintf '0x%x', $1/eg;` .

I am getting two more warnings

**Code part 3**: Here I am checking the max word width present in each columns

```
my @col_lns;
while (<file>) {
  my @row = split " ",$_;
  @col_lns = map ((length) @rows) if $. ==1;

for ( my $col_l =0; $col_l <$#row; $col_l+=1) {
my $col_ln = length $row[$col_l];

  if ($col_lns[$col_l] < $coln)    ###Here I am getting warning
{
  $col_lns[$col_l] = $coln;
}
}
```

**Warning 3:**

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<)
```

**Code part 4**;

```
my $pack1 = substr($add,4,4);
my $pack2 = substr($add,0,4);
```

**Warning 4**

```
Use of $add in substr
substr outside of string
```

Comment: 1a) You used `@array` in one place and `@fields` in another. 1b) You start with the second element and then go one too far `for my $j (0..$#array)`

Comment: 2) `[0-9]*` should be `[0-9]+`

Comment: @ikegami, still getting warnings after changes.

Comment: Don't put undef in the array if you don't want warnings about the undefined elements of the array

Comment: @ikegami, Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem as required

Comment: @ikegami, Can you check the update part. Thanks.

Comment: @HG You should not change the premiss of the question when you have 3 answers. This is new code you are asking about, it should be in a new question. Finish this one and write a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Writing down step by step walkthrough of the code. (Credit to ikegami for mentioning some of this in comments)

Code part 1:

Things wrong with this part:

- You check the length of array `@array`, then use that length to loop over the `@fields` array.
- You start at array index 1 and go to array index equal to array length (assuming the correct array length was used). This is a one-off error. Arrays start at 0. You should loop from 0 to max **index** of array `$#fields` (one less than length).
- Warning 1 does not match what is written in the code. The error should be about array `@fields`, which is what you use in the code.
- Warning 1 gives the wrong line number 270.
  (These last two points indicate that you have altered the code after copying the error message, which is a bad thing to do)
- Warning 1 means that one value in the `@array` array is undefined. Since you have a one-off error in the loop conditions, a good guess is that the undefined value is at the end of the array and that this warning disappears once you fix the loop condition.

Code part 2:

- You are feeding the empty string `""` to `sprintf`, and it warns you about that. Since your match is surrounded by space and single quotes, it is likely an empty string in the input (i.e. `''`). To avoid matching that, you can use `+` instead of `*`, i.e. `[0-9]+`. The quantifier `+` means "match 1 or more times", whereas `*` means "match 0 or more times". Be aware that doing this will also leave the quotes and spaces, which are removed at other times.
- `DATA` is a reserved file handle for in-file data, using the `__DATA__` marker at the bottom of the file. Unless this is what you are doing, you should choose another file handle. Preferably a lexical one, e.g. `my $fh`.

You comment further:

> @ikegami, still getting warnings after changes.

Since you do not mention what those warnings are, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that swapping `@array` to `@fields` is a typo.

Here, you get the number of elements in your array:

```
my $length = @array;
```

So if your array contains five elements, `$length` will now contain 5. The five elements in your array will have the indexes 0 to 4.

Now you walk over the elements of your array:

```
for (my $j=1; $j <= $length; $j+=1) {
  ...
}
```

Obviously, I don't know what is in your array, but it looks weird that you're starting at index 1 - usually, you'd start at index 0. And your code continues until index 5 - but your array doesn't have an index 5. As I said above, your indexes go from 0 to 4.

So you try to access the element at index 5, there is no such element and you get a "undefined value" warning when you try to use that value.

So your code should probably look like this:

```
# Start at 0; continue only while $j is less than $length
for (my $j=0; $j < $length; $j+=1) {
  ...
}
```

However, that's not a very "Perlish" way to write this code. Perl programmers rarely use this "C-style" loop syntax. We like to iterate over a list of values.

```
for my $j (0 .. $#array) {
  ..
}
```

This is exactly equivalent to your original code, but (in my opinion) it's far easier to read.

- `..` : This is the "range operator". It returns a list of the integers between 0 and `$#array`
- `$#array` : Each array has a special variable (`$#arrayname`) associated with it which contains the highest index number in the array. In this case, that will be 4.

But we can improve on this. You don't actually want the array indexes, do you? What you really want is the array **elements**. And you can get those directly.

```
for my $element (@array) {
  if ($element =~ /dat/) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Finally, a Perl programmer would probably use `$_` as the variable here as you don't usually need to actually write it:

```
for (@array) {   # stores each element in turn in $_
  if (/dat/) {   # checks regex against $_
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to change OP's code a little bit to make workable code sample.

Note #1: no input data sample provided by OP

Note: #2: `s/ '([0-9]+)' /sprintf ' 0x%x ', $1/eg;` would be more correct

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array = ( 'First sentence here', undef, 'Second dat sentence', undef, 'One more data sentence');

say '---- Part 1 ----';

for ( @array ) {
    if( defined $_ and /dat/ ) {
        say;
    }
}

say '---- Part 2 ----';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/ '([0-9]*)' /sprintf ' 0x%x ', $1/eg;
    print $_;
}

__DATA__
some test data placed here for a test
ok, lets put some digits '3824' bits
some more '8902' bytes some text
number of files '0x834' you did not account for this
now finish with '123456' number
```

Output

```
---- Part 1 ----
Second dat sentence
One more data sentence
---- Part 2 ----
some test data placed here for a test
ok, lets put some digits 0xef0 bits
some more 0x22c6 bytes some text
number of files '0x834' you did not account for this
now finish with 0x1e240 number
```