# How to remove these warnings in Perl?

Tags: perl, warnings

Here I am checking the max word width present in each columns

```
my @col_lns;
while (<file>) {
  my @row = split " ",$_;
  @col_lns = map ((length) @rows) if $. ==1;

for ( my $col_l =0; $col_l <$#row; $col_l+=1) {
my $col_ln = length $row[$col_l];

  if ($col_lns[$col_l] < $col_ln)    ###Here I am getting warning
{
  $col_lns[$col_l] = $col_ln;
}
}
```

**Warning 1:**

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<)
```

**Code part 2**;

```
my $pack1 = substr($add,4,4);
my $pack2 = substr($add,0,4);
```

**Warning 2**

```
Use of $add in substr
substr outside of string
```

Comment: I'm not able to run your code: `Array found where operator expected at ... line 8, near ") @row"
 (Missing operator before @row?)
syntax error at ..., near ") @row"`

Comment: `map ((length) @rows)` - this is invalid code. I presume you mean either `map { length } @rows` or `map(length, @rows)`.

Comment: `map ((length) @row)` is a syntax error. `@rows` is not declared (violates `strict`). Possible typo from other variable `@row`, which indicates you are not using `use strict`, which is a very bad idea. This code would not run. You should not post code that you have not tried to run. That is very disrespectful to the people who try to answer your question.

Comment: You declare `my $col_ln`, but later on you use `$coln`. Is that on purpose, or a mistake? If you are not using `use strict`, Perl would not object to you "creating" a new variable by mistake and trying to use it, and it would give an uninitialized warning.

Comment: `Use of $add in substr` does not look like a real warning. It looks like you cut away part of the warning, such as `Use of uninitialized value $add in substr`, which would explain the other error (undefined string has length 0).

Comment: @TLP, $coln was mistake .I corrected that in code.

Comment: @HG You should never post questions where the code is not **exactly** how it was when you tried to run it. That defeats the whole purpose of most questions. If you are not using `use strict`, then add that to your program, fix the errors and then edit your question with the fixed code.

Comment: Re "*You should never post questions where the code is not exactly how it was when you tried to run it.*", Correct. But to be clear, we don't want irrelevant details either. Create a minimal runnable snippet that exhibits the problem, run it to make sure it does, and post that.

Comment: Re "*I presume you mean either `map { length } @rows` or `map(length, @rows)`*", You can still use parens with the first syntax. So maybe they wanted `map( { length } @rows )`

Answer (score 4):

It's really not hard to diagnose either of these yourself.

> Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<)

You know the piece of code that is giving this warning:

```
if ($col_lns[$col_l] < $coln)
```

So either `$col_lns[$col_l]` or `$coln` contains `undef` when you're executing this line. If I were unable to work out what the problem is, I would add a print statement that displayed those two values just before executing that line of code. I'd probably also throw in `$col_l` to show which element of the array we're looking at.

Given the confusion in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585778/perl-can-anyone-tell-me-how-to-resolve-this-warnings) and the fact that you're still using the C-style `for` loop that you've been advised against, I'd be pretty sure that this is caused by you going off the end of your array.

> Use of $add in substr

> substr outside of string

The first warning there is strange. It doesn't look like a Perl warning to me. Have you edited it too much? But the second is clear. You're trying to take a substring, but using values that fall outside of the length of your source string. Once again, you can investigate this by printing the values that you're using in your code.

It might be worth pointing out that there is a [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag) manual page which contains all of Perl's errors and warnings alongside more detailed explanations of what they mean. You can get those explanations displayed at runtime by adding [`use diagnostics`](https://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics) to your code - but please remove it once the problems are fixed.

Comment: Re "*The first warning there is strange. [...] Have you edited it too much?*", It's surely supposed to be `Use of uninitialized value $add in substr`. That also explains the subsequent warning. The stringification of `undef` is the empty string, so `substr(undef,4,4)` is equivalent to `substr("",4,4)` (aside from the warning), leading to the second warning. The point is that fixing the first will probably fix the second.