# How to resolve this warning in Perl

Tags: perl

I asked this type of ques [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589416/how-to-remove-this-warnings-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment114230380_64589416) but didn't provide the full code.

I am reading below file and checking the max word width present in each column and then write it to another file with proper alignment.

```
id0 id1 id2 batch
0   34  56  70
2   3647    58  72  566
4   39  616 75  98  78 78987 9876 7899 776
89  40  62  76
8   42  64  78
34  455 544 565
```

My code:

```
unlink "temp1.log";
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
my $log1_file = "log1.log";
my $temp1 = "temp1.log";
open(IN1, "<$log1_file" ) or die "Could not open file $log1_file: $!";
my @col_lens;

while (my $line = <IN1>) {
    my @fs = split " ", $line;
    my @rows = @fs ;
    @col_lens =  map (length, @rows) if $.==1;
    for my $col_idx (0..$#rows) {
        my $col_len = length $rows[$col_idx];
        if ($col_lens[$col_idx] < $col_len) {
            $col_lens[$col_idx] = $col_len;
        }
    };
};
close IN1;
open(IN1, "<$log1_file" ) or die "Could not open file $log1_file: $!";
open(tempp1,"+>>$temp1") or die "Could not open file $temp1: $!";
while (my $line = <IN1>) {
    my @fs = split " ", $line;
    my @az;
    for my $h (0..$#fs) { 
        my $len = length $fs[$h]; 
        my $blk_len = $col_lens[$h]+1;
        my $right = $blk_len - $len;
        $az[$h] = (" ") . $fs[$h] . ( " " x $right );
    }
    say tempp1 (join "|",@az);
};
```

My warning

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at new.pl line 25, <IN1> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at new.pl line 25, <IN1> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at new.pl line 25, <IN1> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at new.pl line 25, <IN1> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at new.pl line 25, <IN1> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at new.pl line 25, <IN1> line 4.
```

I am getting the output correctly but don't know how to remove this warnings.

Comment: Put this line at the beginning - `no warnings 'uninitialized';`

Comment: @vkk05 that will silence the warnings, not fix them.

Comment: @simbabque: Right. Means its not recommend to put this line?

Comment: @vkk05  warnings are there for a reason. Simply turning them off is not good advice. However, your answer is really good. In this case, it's probably fine to turn them off, but I believe if that advice is given, the reasoning should be explained on here.

Comment: What is causing the warnings? Array col_lens only has 4 entries in array then on line 3 of the file there are 5 values, so it doing a comparision on value 5 from the file (566) to an uninitialised value from the Array col_lens eg $col_lens[4].  This is also what is causing the warnings on line 4 of the file.

Comment: @simbabque _warnings are there for a reason_ I totally agree. I don't want to OP to simply turning them off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$col_idx` can be up to the number of fields on a line, minus one. For the third line, this is more than the highest index of `@col_lens`, which contains at most 3 elements. So doing the following makes no sense:

```perl
if ($col_lens[$col_idx] < $col_len) {
   $col_lens[$col_idx] = $col_len;
}
```

Replace it with

```
if (!defined($col_lens[$col_idx]) || $col_lens[$col_idx] < $col_len) {
   $col_lens[$col_idx] = $col_len;
}
```

With this, there's really no point checking for `$. == 1` anymore.

Comment: Adjusted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting `uninitialized` warning because, while checking the `$col_lens[$col_idx] < $col_len` condition, one or both of them are `undef`.

**Solution 1:**

You can skip checking this condition by the use of `next` statement.

```
for my $col_idx (0..$#rows) {
        my $col_len = length $rows[$col_idx];
        
        next unless $col_lens[$col_idx];
        
        if ($col_lens[$col_idx] < $col_len) {
            $col_lens[$col_idx] = $col_len;
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2: (Not advised):**

You can simply ignore `Use of uninitialized value..` warnings by putting this line at top of your script. This will disable `uninitialized` warnings in a block.

```
no warnings 'uninitialized';
```

For more info, please refer this [link](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings)

Comment: Solution 1 not working getting other warnings ```Use of uninitialized value within @col_lens in addition (+) at new.pl line 47, <IN1> line 3.  &  
Negative repeat count does nothing at new.pl line 49, <IN1> line 3. ```

Comment: @H G : Did you altered the input log file to do this testing?

Answer (score 1):

Following code demonstrates one of many possible ways for solution to this task

- read line by line
- get length of each field
- compare with stored earlier
- adjust to max length
- form `$format` string for print
- print formatted data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my(@data,@length,$format);

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my @e = split ' ';
    my @l = map{ length } @e;
    $length[$_] = ($length[$_] // 0) < $l[$_] ? $l[$_] : $length[$_] for 0..$#e;
    push @data,\@e;
}

$format = join '  ', map{ '%'.$_.'s' } @length;
$format .= "\n";

for my $row ( @data ) {
    printf $format, map { $row->[$_] // '' } 0..$#length;;
}

__DATA__
id0 id1 id2 batch
0   34  56  70
2   3647    58  72  566
4   39  616 75  98  78 78987 9876 7899 776
89  40  62  76
8   42  64  78
34  455 544 565
```

Output

```
id0   id1  id2  batch
  0    34   56     70
  2  3647   58     72  566
  4    39  616     75   98  78  78987  9876  7899  776
 89    40   62     76
  8    42   64     78
 34   455  544    565
```